# How to replace the last column of a csv file whre the value is greater than 0

Tags: python, csv, replace, dataset

I have this large dataset where I want to replace the value of the last column with 1.

for example:

```
1,1,34
1,2,32
1,3,0
1,4,12
```

I need to be able to change the value in the last column to 1 where the value is greater than 0.

example output:

```
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,0
1,4,1
```

could someone please help?
so far I have been able to replace the last character, but I can't seem to find out how to replace the entire column no matter the value

[addition]

i have tried this for now

```
lines = [line.replace("2\n","1\n") for line in lines]
lines = [line.replace("3\n","1\n") for line in lines]
```

and so on..

but this wouldn't cover the entire spectrum of numbers obviously

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried.

Comment: also, i am not aware of what the greatest possible value is, so i didn't attempt writing a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and not using any external modules:

```
with open('/path/to/data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [list(map(float, l.strip().split(',')))  for l in f.readlines()]
data = [x[:-1] + ([1] if x[-1] else [0]) for x in data]
```

Can be made a 1-liner:

```
data = [list(map(float, l.strip().split(',')))[:-1] + ([1] if list(map(int, l.strip().split(',')))[-1] else [0]) for l in open(r"C:\Users\ShlomiF\Documents\new 3.txt", 'r').readlines()]
```

But that's anti-python-zen :-)

---

Edit:
Writing back to file is just reversing the above:

```
with open('/path/to/file/of/choice.txt', 'w') as f:  # Can be same file
    for x in data:
        f.write(','.join(list(map(str, x))) + '\n')
```

Comment: it worked! just had to replace the int with float, otherwise i got an error.
thanks! :D

Comment: Glad I can help :-)

Comment: You want to save the new file? I'll add that now.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to create a new csv from existing one with the updated values.
Sample code is below.

```
import csv
with open(r'C:\Users\gupta\Desktop\csvfile.csv') as inputFile:
    x = csv.reader(inputFile)
    for lines in x:
        if int(lines[-1]) > 0:
           lines[-1] = 1
        with open(r'C:\Users\gupta\Desktop\csvfile1.csv','a') as outFile:
            iWrite = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=' ')
            iWrite.writerow(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas and a lambda function.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(<your csv>, headers=None)

data.iloc[:, -1] = data.iloc[:, -1].apply([lambda x: x if x <= 1 else 1])
data.to_csv(<your csv>, index=False, header=False)
```

The lambda function checks if a value in the last column (the `-1` in `data.iloc[:, -1]`) is bigger than 1 and replaces it with 1 if that's the case.

this creates the output:

```
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,0
1,4,1
```

Comment: this creates an output similar to this:

1,1,1,
2,1,2,
3,1,3,
4,1,4,

so it pretty much ends up naming the columns and just removes the last one :/

Comment: I made an edit. This explicitly says that there are no headers and removes the index in the CSV-output.

Comment: But I don't understand why it removes the last column like you said. It doesn't do that when I run it...

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex:

```
import re


data = ["1,1,34",
        "1,2,32",
        "1,3,0",
        "1,4,12"]

pattern = r"^([0-9]+,[0-9]+),(?:[2-9]|\d\d\d*)$"

for line in data:
    if re.match(pattern, line):
        line = re.sub(pattern, r"\1,1", line)
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,0
1,4,1
```